# SharePoint 2013 - Webpart added by powershell but it does not display when view by edit mode on web browser

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, web-parts

*** I used SharePoint Powershell(2013)  to add a webpart to a page

*** Affer added webpart success from powershell, then I go to the page, I saw the webpart be added to the page(I also saw the webpart in Web Part Page Maintenance )

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

*** But when I show page by edit mode, I don't find the webpart.

[image: Screenshot 3]

*** Can you help me how to add a webpart from powershell but I still can edit the webpart in edit mode of the page on web browser?

Here is my powershell script:

```
function NewGuid(){
    $id = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
    return "g_" + $id.Replace("-","_") 
}

function Add-ContentEditorWebPart()
{
    $SiteURL = "https://insiderdev.connorgp.com"
    $pageUrl = "https://insiderdev.connorgp.com/ConnorGroup/SitePages/NhanTest1.aspx"
    $webpartzone = "Header"
    $index = 1
    $title = "Content Editor"

    $site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($SiteURL)
    $web=$site.OpenWeb()

    $webpartmanager = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($pageUrl, [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)

    $webpart = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart    
    $webpart.ChromeType = "None"
    $webpart.Title = $title 
    $webpart.ID = NewGuid
    $webpart.FrameType = "None" 
    $webpart.CatalogIconImageUrl = "/_layouts/15/images/mscontl.gif"
    $webpart.PartImageLarge = "/_layouts/15/images/mscontl.gif"

    $content = "Test Webpart added"
    $docXml = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
    $contentXml = $docXml.CreateElement("Content")
    $contentXml.set_InnerText($content)
    $docXml.AppendChild($contentXml)    
    $webpart.Content = $contentXml

    $webpartmanager.AddWebPart($webpart, $webpartzone, $index)

    $web.Close()
    $site.Close()
}

Add-ContentEditorWebPart
```

Comment: Any people, do you know the issue or give me any suggestion  to resolve the issue? :)

Comment: Did you ever get solution to this problem?